Get confused and collapsed on Fragment LifeCycle of Android
As a beginner, I am learning android and currently I want to learn the concept of Fragment and the Life Cycle of Fragment. But I got more and more confused after I search information in the internet due very limited resource and incomplete examples (some are even deprecated). I would like to ask the several questions:

I googled the life cycle of fragment and I found out two graphs to demonstrate the whole life cycle of
a fragment:

and

It looks that they are different as the latter has some voids that the former does not have (onCreateView(), onDestroyView()...). Which one is correct?

When I learn the concept of life cycle of an activity, I was given the concept of this graph:

Is this concept same as the graphs I showed in question 1. If not, how different they are?

When I googled the concept of LifeCycle of a Fragment, many of the sources suggested that I shall use
DefaultLifecycleObserver and LifecycleOwner. Can anyone provide me a complete and most important, an
example(java please) as simpleas possible (maybe just consist of log.e())? Because it would be
very difficult for a beginner to combine many broken pieces back to a complete script.



As an Android programmer, I understand that the lifecycle is bewildering.  You should be able to find many technical blog posts that break down the lifecycle.  Now, your question isn't a good fit for this forum; I would suggest you submit a question with some code for a specific feature you're trying to implement using the lifecycle.
